# How to listen to 'after' event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding a new element dynamically via JQuery, with code like the below:

```
$('#example').after("<p class='xx'></p>")
```

Upon this code being called and a "xx" element being added, I'd like to run some other code. How can I 'listen' and pick up when this event happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for this.

The demo below is a simple quick adaptation of the example in reference.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var targetNode = document.getElementById('some-id');
  var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
  var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
      if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
        console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
      }
    }
  };
  var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
  observer.observe(targetNode, config);

  $('#example').after("<p class='xx'>I am a paragraph inserted by a script.</p>");
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="some-id">
  <p id="example">I'm a static paragraph.</p>
</div>
```